# How to execute the python script in php with different path?

Tags: php, python-3.x

I have a php file which store in **C:/localhost**

**try.php**

```
<?php
echo exec('python resizer.py');
?>
```

Above code **only allowed** me to run the **python script** that store under **C:/localhost**

My problem now is I not able to run the script that store in different path from the php file.

For example now my **resizer.py** is stored in **C:/Hello/images**, and my php file is stored in **C:/localhost**, so how i going to execute the python script in php file in different path?

Can share me some ideas? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Did you try 
    exec('python C:/Hello/images/resizer.py')

Comment: yes but cannot work also